# What are the doors on a bus called?

Tags: word-request, nouns

What are the doors on a bus called?
How do you describe the doors in the front and the back?
Is it *door* or *entrance*? Is it *front* or *forward*, *back* or *rear*?

Examples of where it could be used:

> The people waiting at the bus-stop formed a line to the x
>
> The bus stopped outside the store and he got off through the x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I offer you [this Transport for London Government website](https://tfl.gov.uk/modes/buses/new-routemaster) talking about their new double-decker buses, where they describe the staircases:

> two staircases, one near the front and one at the back

But they describe the doors:

> the rear doors will be operated by the driver.

I vote that the "front and rear doors" are "at the front and back of the bus", and "forward doors" doesn't sound right at all.

Comment: I don't like _forward doors_, either, but it sounds okay to me in the singular: _Please exit from the forward door._ (I have no problem with that instruction.)

Comment: I think I'd expect a forward door on an Isetta, not a bus.

Comment: @Random832 Or on a vessel.

Comment: Actually, the "rear" door may be near the _center_ of the bus, but it is farther _toward_ the rear than the front door is!

Comment: If there was a "forward" door, wouldn't we expect the other one to be called "aft", as on a vessel?  Jus' wonderin'.